# I need ssl in my redis or not is required

Tags: ssl, redis, openssl

i have password with "Config set require pass", my app web use HTTPS. How dangerous is it not to use ssl with redis? it is required?

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends on your implementation.

if it's setup in trusted private network then it's perfectly okay to not use SSL.

However if your Redis-client talk to your Redis-server over the public network then it's wise to implement a SSL encrypted connections.

You can check out this article for more read https://redislabs.com/blog/stunnel-secure-redis-ssl/